# C# Show/hide element on MouseHover/MouseLeave of the parent

Tags: c#, visible, mouseleave, mousehover

In C#, we have the following:

- A `UserControl` containing a `PictureBox` and an invisible `FlowPanel`.

What I want to achieve:

- When the `UserControl` is hovered
  (`MouseHover`), the invisible
  `FlowPanel` will be set to `visible =
  true`. When the mouse leaves the
  `UserControl` *or* `FlowPanel`, the
  `FlowPanel` should be set `visible =
  false`.

Using `MouseLeave` on `UserControl` doesn't do the job, because this event is triggered when the mouse enters `FlowPanel`. Hiding the `FlowPanel` when the mouse leaves `FlowPanel` does it, but is buggy (sometimes `MouseLeave` is triggered, sometimes not).

What's the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i did somthing similar on one of my forms

do a if(contorl.Opacity = 1.0) inside your first event

```
private void Form1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (this.ClientRectangle.Contains(this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
   {
    this.Opacity = 1.0;
   }
   else
   {
      int loopctr = 0;

      for (loopctr = 100; loopctr >= 5; loopctr -= 10)
      {
        this.Opacity = loopctr / 99.0;
        this.Refresh();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This helps me with setting a transparent background, but doesn't solve the problem. When you move your mouse fast, the problem consists.

Comment: you cold set a timer to check if the Mouse cursor is in bounds, if not inbounds set Opacity to 0.0

Answer (score 0):

In the case when `FlowPanel.MouseLeave` isn't triggered, isn't `UserControl.MouseLeave` triggered? I suppose that hiding on both events may do the trick.

Comment: This makes the FlowPanel flicker, since UserControl triggers MouseLeave when the FlowPanel is shown.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common UI problem. Mouse events come up as samples so it's possible that some pixel positions are missed and a control doesn't get the mouse up event.

A not so nice way that works is setting up some form of Timer when MouseHover is detected inside the Control and poll for the cursor in regular intervals (such as 342ms).